# What's "A Slave" in "12 Years A Slave"?

Tags: inversion, adjuncts, predicative-complement

A grammatical analysis of the title for the movie "[12 Years A Slave](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2024544/)" has baffled me. Particularly the fact that possibly some kind of inversion (*A Slave **for** 12 Years* ⟶ *12 Years A Slave*) has taken place.

What's the role of "A Slave" in this phrase?

Some other examples:

> I know the meaning of **those nineteen years a slave** of the law! – Jean Valjean

> All things considered, then, it came as no great surprise when Mrs. LaPointe, **two years a widow**, stepped out to retrieve her newspaper one morning and spotted a dead doe in the middle of Shady Dell Lane. – “Bonny Oaks,” Michael Knight, The Saturday Evening Post, July, 2012

Comment: You have it exactly correct, but I have no idea what to call that grammatical construct, so I'm not going to write an answer.  Another example I can think of, though, is the song 'Three Times a Lady'.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's no reason to suppose movie titles should be "sentences", so it's pointless trying to analyse their "syntax" from that perspective
.

Comment: @Fumble Of course very few movie titles would be more than a phrase, but I thought this was a minor clause rather than just a phrase. Do I need to adjust my wording to ask about the inversion?

Comment: I think you can understand it by making it a predicative complement in a larger sentence: *I was twelve years a slave.*

Comment: @snailplane wouldn't "I was a twelve-year slave" be better? I wonder how "I was twelve years a slave" could work.

Comment: If you want to see it in the context of more conventional syntax, perhaps consider *[He spent] 12 years **as** a slave*.

Comment: There are many books with titles with a similar structure. The usage seems to be in quite rapid decline since 1920, so maybe it was considered a more normal structure in past times. See this NGram https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=years+a&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyears%20a%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Fumble edited with some other examples. I hope I deserve your mercy now. :)

Comment: @JavaLatte When you use Ngram, you need to read and check what those related links show. Using "years a" can't be as objective as you might have expected.

Comment: @Ranthony: I did. If you had also done so, you would have found that most of the examples that were good structural matches were book titles, as I stated. "50 years a doctor", "forty years a gambler", "thirty years a slave", "forty years a fur trader", "forty years a chief"... etc, etc..

Comment: @JavaLatte: Syntactically, *12 years a slave* seems to me to be much the same as [*twice a winner*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=twice+a+winner&year_start=1880&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=30&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctwice%20a%20winner%3B%2Cc0), and that NGram link suggests the usage is actually *gaining* traction, not declining. Whatever - it doesn't seem like a "dated" form to me, just a bit "formal, literary".

Comment: @JavaLatte One of your links shows "220 Years ... a History of the Catholic Community of the Frederick Valley". I am not disputing the fact that the construction could work, but I'm just saying using Ngram with only "years a" is tricky and could be misleading.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I think that social factors are at play here. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=twice+a+winner%2Ctwice+a+widow&year_start=1880&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=30&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctwice%20a%20winner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctwice%20a%20widow%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Please don't vote to close this question. It asks about an important and subtle aspect of English grammar. Movie titles do have syntax (see "A Star Is Born" explained [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/49027/6700)), grammar is not limited to full sentences, and this particular grammatical construction shows up in ordinary sentences, too.

Comment: "If you want to see it in the context of more conventional syntax, perhaps consider [He spent] 12 years as a slave." <-- But that's a completely different construction. PhMgBr is asking about the grammatical relations of the word *slave* within a specific type of predicative complement. In your example it's the complement of a preposition. It's not the complement of a preposition in the OQ.

Comment: @JavaLatte: Check out [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=twice+a+winner%2Ctwice+a+widow%2Ctwice+widowed&year_start=1880&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=30&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctwice%20a%20winner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctwice%20a%20widow%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctwice%20widowed%3B%2Cc0) showing how ***twice widowed*** displaced ***twice a widow*** back in the 20s. That suggests it's prolly not so much "social factors" - more a matter of a linguistic trend towards avoiding the ***[n-times] a [noun]*** construction, with no tendency to also avoid ***[n-times] [adjective]***.

Answer (score 2):

Three points have been raised about this text:

- it's not a complete sentence
- the word order seems unusual
- there appears to be two nouns but no prepositions.

The fact that it's not a complete sentence is irrelevant: this is normal for titles of films and books. There are many examples of complete sentences that use the same construction, and the OP has added now added two of them to his question.

The film is from an autobiographical book, so I think we can reasonably analyse the title as if it were a predicate complement of **I was**.

> I was twelve years a slave.

It seems to me that **a slave** would also make sense as a predicate complement on its own:

> I was a slave.

so the unusual part is not "a slave" but "twelve years".

Regarding the word order, some people have pointed out the similarity to sentences like "twice a winner", rather than "a winner twice". Note that twice is an adverb, and adverb positioning can be flexible. Yes, there are 'rules', but these rules are really guidelines, and they change over time and with regional dialects.

The final point is about the absence of prepositions. There are many examples of sentences that concern time periods and do not have prepositions, some of which show this inversion. As the book was published in 1853, I have picked some examples from the 19th century, though it is possible to find examples back to the 16th century that show the absence of preposition and the inversion.

> When I met Wolseley first, in 1877, he had been but twenty-one years a soldier
>
> [He was] two weeks an invalid (1882)
>
> He was out of the prison about ten months (1881)
>
> [She is] now a widow, and in the house nearly five years with her oldest child (1882)

I am wondering whether these time intervals are treated as adverbs of time duration, like **long**. This would explain the absence of preposition and also the flexibility in positioning:

> She did not **long** remain a widow (1824)
>
> [I] began to think I should not be a soldier **long** (1853)

Answer (score -3):

I think this is [headlinese](/questions/tagged/headlinese), that is, shortened non-standard language used mainly for titles of newspaper articles - but apparently it fits book and movie titles as well. I can easily imagine a magazine title like "Twelve years a slave: a shocking report".

Another possible explanation is dialect: the hero/protagonist is a 19th-century African American and has lived among slaves for a long time, so although the syntax that he uses seems substandard to us, it might have been common for these times and places.

Comment: Considering the usage, I don't think it's fair to call it "headlinese"... Your secondary is much more likely than that.

Comment: Interesting guesses, but neither sounds reasonable to me. This has a poetic ring to it, more than headline-like or dialectal.

Comment: It couldn't be headlinese. It just couldn't. They haven't picked fights with prepositions.

Comment: If you think it's not headlinese, please identify the verb in this "sentence".

Comment: @laugh Many book and movie titles don't have verbs but aren't in headlinese. For example, [_The Hustler_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hustler_(film)), [_Star Wars_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars). There are even ordinary spoken sentences that lack a verb, like "The more, the merrier" and "[Off with his head!](https://books.google.com/books?id=ddQIbwrBBd0C&dq=%22off%20with%20his%20head%22%20alice%20queen&pg=PA54#v=onepage&q=%22off%20with%20his%20head%22&f=false)"

Comment: @Laugh if it doesn't have a verb, it's headlinese? By that description, "If only!" is headlinese.

Comment: No verb: headlinese? Hardly.